# How to execute an if statement inside textbox onEnter function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have some code on my document.ready function which must get the scanned barcode from a textbox. But if there is nothing inside the textbox a pop up appears to tell the user to scan something. I have a button that does all that perfectly, but wen i use the enter key on my textbox, the pop up doesnt appear. What might be wrong? I am using JQuery Mobile.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#txtBarcode").focus();
    $("#btnBarcode").click(getBarcode);

    var imageContainer = document.getElementById("divImage");

    $('#txtBarcode').live("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        getBarcode();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any errors? `live` was removed in 1.9 version.

Comment: Which version of JQuery are you using? Its working for me if I use bind instead of live. http://jsfiddle.net/Qckzq/

Comment: The ENTER key might submit the form? tried http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ ?

Comment: No problems with your code.
Please, check:
http://jsfiddle.net/inser/2JPB8/1/

Comment: @dfsq no errors, but it is supposed to check the condition (if the textbox is empty or not) before, and then execute accordingly. The getBarcode function ignores the condition and executes even if my textbox is empty if i pressed enter on my keyboard. But when i clicked the button, getBarcode function first cheks the condition and den executes accordinigly.

Comment: @Subir Kumar sao 1.3.0. let me then try bind instead

Comment: @inser ok, let me try that. i now think there might be something wrong with my getBarcode function, but then it works fine when i click the button. Here is my code...

Comment: function getBarcode() {
    var imageContainer = document.getElementById("divImage");
    document.getElementById("divImage").innerHTML = "";
    var barcode = $("#txtBarcode").val();

    if (barcode.length != 0) {
            //do abc...
            $("#txtBarcode").focus();
        }
        else {
            //do 123....
            $("#txtBarcode").focus();
        }
  }

Comment: update your question with `getBarcode()` function.